# Unable to retrieve data for displaying in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a web app where I can login using Firebase. I know the details are stored in the Firebase database. I want the username value to be displayed on the browser in a certain field. Here are the screenshots.

This is the firebase data. In this picture, see the username karthik babu.
[image: This image is where you see the firebase database.]

I want that username to be displayed on the area in the picture below:
[image: This is where I need the username to be displayed.]

So, instead of the username, I need the actual username value to be displayed.

Here is the code I tried:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); 
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(user) {
        var token = user.credential.accessToken;
        var user = user.user;
 var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("WoofyDesktop/UserList");
        if (user) {
          usersRef.child(user.uid).set({ 
 useremail: user.email,
 useruid: user.uid,
            username: user.displayName
 });
```

firebase retrieve code i tried:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("UserList");
  rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

var username = snap.child("username").val();

  $("username").append("<div><a><label>" + username + "</label></a></div>");
  console.log(username);

  });
```

html code for username..

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="user">
 <label for="username" id="username" >username</label>


    </a></div>
```

Any suggestions on how or what I should change for displaying the required data?

Edit: Tried the updated query as in the answer by aks79 and this is what I am getting. Any insights?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed another label inside a label tag
Limitations of label tag...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label
use a different tag like div instead

try using it like

HTML Code

```
    <div class="user" id="username"></div>
```

and the jquery as

```
 $("#username").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)'><label>" + username + "</label></a>");
```

Comment: Cn you please see the edits. Syntax error is what I am getting. Tried inserting and removing the }, ) etc. with no results.

Comment: $("#username").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)'><label>" + username + "</label></a>");
@BizDev try this... the double quotes are giving an issue

Comment: Yep. Already tried that. The syntax error is cleared. However, no output :(